# Error: Cannot GET / [QUASAR FRAMEWORK] [HEROKU DEPLOYEMENT]

Tags: express, heroku, static, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to publish my Quasar app on Heroku. I'm using Express to serve my front.

I succeed to publish my app on Heroku with that link: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-spa/deploying.
My application is deployed on https://coronavirus-statistics-app.herokuapp.com/  but when I try to access it, I got an error "Cannot GET /".

My server file:

```
const
  express = require('express'),
  serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
  history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
  port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()
app.use(history())
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/dist/spa'))
app.listen(port)
```

In local, I can access to my application at http://localhost:5000/#/home and my different views http://localhost:5000/#/table, http://localhost:5000/#/about ...

My log from Heroku deployement:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >= 10.18.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   >= 6.13.4
       engines.yarn (package.json):  >= 1.21.1
       
       Resolving node version >= 10.18.1...
       Downloading and installing node 15.11.0...
       Bootstrapping npm >= 6.13.4 (replacing 7.6.0)...
       npm >= 6.13.4 installed
       Resolving yarn version >= 1.21.1...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
       Installed yarn 1.22.10
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 1377 packages, and audited 1378 packages in 43s
       
       1 high severity vulnerability
       
       To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > corona-app@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild
       > yarn && yarn build
       
       yarn install v1.22.10
       info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
       [1/5] Validating package.json...
       [2/5] Resolving packages...
warning axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @quasar/app > chokidar > fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @quasar/app > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @quasar/app > stylus > css-parse > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
       [3/5] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [4/5] Linking dependencies...
       [5/5] Building fresh packages...
       success Saved lockfile.
       Done in 35.33s.
       yarn run v1.22.10
       $ yarn
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
       [1/5] Validating package.json...
       [2/5] Resolving packages...
       success Already up-to-date.
       Done in 1.44s.
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       added 7 packages, removed 6 packages, and audited 70 packages in 4s
       
       1 high severity vulnerability
       
       To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 44.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v8
       https://coronavirus-statistics-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

My logs from Heroku when I try to reach my app:

```
2021-03-07T10:10:06.024914+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/spa/index.html'
2021-03-07T10:10:06.025410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=coronavirus-statistics-app.herokuapp.com request_id=86909de1-ee05-4c15-ae11-16a2f0bab822 fwd="183.182.112.106" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
```

How to solve the problem?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to server the index.html file from your express server.

```
const
  express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
  history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
  port = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express()
app.use(history())
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/dist/spa'))
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/spa/index.html'));
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/spa', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port);
```

Make sure 'dist/spa' folder exist in Heroku and you've haven't added it to your .gitignore file or haven't checked it into git.

Finally, the reason ENOENT says /app/dist is just because your root/home directory on Heroku is /app. Never build apps that are locked into an absolute file structure; just use relative paths as below.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/spa', 'index.html'));
OR
res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/spa')});
```

**Note**: __dirname returns the directory that the currently executing script is in.

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunatly it's not working :(
I have a new error displayed: "Not Found" :(

Comment: @DamTan Can you paste the error from the log?

Comment: I tryed with: app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/spa/index.html'))); but still the same problem

Comment: the log indicates "/app/dist/spa/index.html", it should not be only /dist/spa/index.html ? My server file is in the same folder as the dist folder

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem because of you :)
My problem was I had to comment the /dist line in my .gitignore file ! That's why it doesn't find my index.html ...

Comment: @DamTan Glad i was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If somebody still has issue with Quasar and history mode you need also to check in `quasar.conf.js` for this:

```
build: {
  vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
```

For me by default it was on hash, and putting the router to history was not enough.